# How to make a page private

Tags: css, html, web, admin

Idea:

Making certain pages private. Say I have 4 navigation links, when the private libk is clicked you will be prompted to enter a correct username and password. On my current practice website I have about 7 links that lead to different pages and I am trying to make one private for personal reasons.

I searched on google, but couldn't find a solution to my situation. Any tutorials would be helpful too. If any part of my code is needed please ask.

Comment: Are you using anything besides straight HTML?  Such as PHP, ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC, Perl, etc?

Comment: What web server are you using? Apache? IIS?

Comment: I'm using godaddy, Windows IIS. Please let me know if I am not clear.

Answer (score 1):

This document on GoDaddy's support site shows how to setup authentication for certain directories with GoDaddy's Windows-based hosting:

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3977/password-protecting-web-directories-on-a-windows-hosting-account

From the document:

- To Restrict Web Access to a Directory Using the FTP File Manager
- Log in to your Account Manager.
- Click Web Hosting.
- Next to the hosting account you want to use, click Launch.
- From the Tools section, click FTP File Manager.
- Select the appropriate existing directory or Create New Directory.

  - If creating a new directory, enter the directory name.
  - Click OK.
  - Select the new directory.
- Click the Permissions icon in the action bar.
- Make sure Read is not checked.
- Click OK.

Comment: Thank you. I followed your steps, but when i enter the username and password it won't access. Would you know how to setup a specific username and password just for this page?